# Show file upload progress in Essence framework

Tags: ajax, file-upload, reactjs, material-design, essence

So I have a simple upload file form and I want to use [`essence-progress`](http://getessence.io/react-component/progress) as a loading spinner while the file is being uploaded. I use XMLHttpRequest2 so I can track my progress and I get in real time the percent left.

Can essence-progress display that percentage number?

I'm thinking something like this:

```
<FileUpload>
   <Progress progress={'progress'} type={'circle'} />
</FileUpload>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into the source code of `essence-progress` I don't think there is a direct way of doing this. However, you could maybe build a new component, something like this:

```
<FileUpload>
   <Progress type={'circle'} />
   <Percentage value={'progress'} />
</FileUpload>
```

as a quick way to solve this issue. And with CSS you position it on top of the progress bar.

I hope this helps. Keep me posted :)